# Tkinter - expand widget in python 3.2

Tags: tkinter, python-3.2

I'm using Tkinter to create a GUI for a python script, and I want to have expandable widgets in the GUI. I'm trying to use the "fill" and "expand" properties in the pack function, but every time I compile the code in python 3.2 I get this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-expand"
```

This properties aren't supported in python 3.2 ?

Comment: can you show the code that is causing the error? Otherwise we have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing has changed with regard to the `expand` or `fill` attributes. Here's a working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        for i in range(1,11):
            label = tk.Label(self, text="This is item #%s" % i,
                             borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
            label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=1)

app = ExampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: My bad, too many hours in front of the screen, I was trying to use the properties when creating the widget, instead of using it in the pack() function.